# How To UPDATE 2 MySQL Tables With Server Event

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I'm creating a website for a simple poll from registered users. Every month, registered users only allowed to vote 5x for a poll.

Now, i'm going to create a server event with HEIDI SQL on 2 tables which will reset their 5 times votes on each month to 0

Here's my exe code:

```
CREATE EVENT `resetvalue`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2017-10-01 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'Im going to reset this every month'
    DO BEGIN

UPDATE tbl_users SET statusmonth = 0
UPDATE tbl_poll SET status1 = 0
UPDATE tbl_poll SET status2 = 0

END
```

Is this the correct code?

Unfortunately, I asked my friend and then he gave another code that look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE EVENT `dbname`.`resetvalue` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH 
STARTS '2011-06-21 01:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO BEGIN


/(sql_statements) 

END$$



DELIMITER ;
```

I got confused, which one is the correct code? What is a DELIMiTER anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a difference for your event with respect to your friend's event.

Your event will run on 1st of every month at 12:00 am and start date of event is 2017-10-01 00:00:00 but your friend's event will run on 21st at 12:00 am of every month and start date is 2011-06-21 01:00:00.

Your event will not deleted once event is completed. But your friend's event code will be removed once it will done. Here both events are never ending it's affect only if it's 5 times to run or you disable an event.

Other then this I think it's same. For more details you can refer MySQL event scheduler documentation.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html